# Can you transcribe the saying from 14:50 to 14:60 in this video?

Tags: listening

I need to transcribe a short text read by Alan Watts in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osEVlaMX6t4

The text is from 14:50 to 14:60. 
This is what I heard but I'm not sure it is correct.

> "...is a certain extraordinary lack of depth..."

**Can you transcribe a complete sentence that have above text?**

Comment: I think you mean "_transcribe_ the saying" (which means "to represent in written characters").  To dictate means "to speak out loud".

Answer (score 1):

> "...is a certain extraordinary lack of depth..."

You are understanding correctly.

Also, you can link to a spot in a youtube video by adding and "&t=MmSs" where the capital letters are the time in minutes and seconds.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osEVlaMX6t4&t=14m50s

Comment: can u dictate a complete sentence

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment of some sort.  The sentence actually starts at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osEVlaMX6t4&t=14m39s  Why don't you give it a shot and post what you think you here and I will help you out.

Comment: Cool tip about jumping to MMSS!